# where can Mybatis get #{id} when I use statement of "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = #{id}"

Tags: mybatis

```
<mapper namespace = "com.my">
<delete id="deleteById">
        DELETE FROM table
        WHERE id = #{id}
</delete>
</mapper>
```

Code above.

Where does Mybatis get the value of #{id},must I code a resultMap in the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is com.my Assuming there is class named MyClass under package com.my

On your DAO I believe you have use something like

```
session.delete("deleteById", com.my.MyClass object);
```

and I believe your class com.my.MyClass have something like

```
private String id;
```

and your xml would be

```
<delete id="deleteById" parameterType="com.my.MyClass">
        DELETE FROM table
        WHERE id = #{id}
</delete>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

Assume MyClass.xml as below:

```
<mapper namespace = "com.my.MyClass">
   <delete id="deleteById">
    DELETE FROM table
    WHERE id = #{id}
   </delete>
</mapper>
```

Then

```
public class MyClass{
   public int deleteById( @Param("id") int id );
}
```